# Simulate bitrot/corrupt files (for BTRFS)

Tags: btrfs, corruption

Is it possible to intentionally corrupt a file so that BTRFS will report a checksum error? I want to test a script that's supposed to find file names with checksum errors, but I don't have any corrupt files.

EDIT: After a long time of searching I found the [same question on AskUbuntu with some solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406463/how-can-i-flip-a-single-bit-in-a-file). Unfortunately, I don't see any `btrfs-corrupt-block` utility, despite the fact that I have `btrfs-progs` installed.

Comment: You probably mean "corrupt a filesystem" ?

Comment: Have you tried disk mapper device backed up by "error" target ? You can find details [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870696/simulate-a-faulty-block-device-with-read-errors)

Answer (score 2):

That the `btrfs-corrupt-block` is not in the `btrfs-progs` packages is probably because the developers did not want the average user to accidentally start it and corrupt anything. The program is not a target in the `btrfs-progs`' `Makefile` and would not be compiled and included by a package builder unless they applied a distro specific patch first. The program is more of a testing tool for developers of `btrfs`.

The source however is in [the main repository](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/mason/btrfs-progs.git/tree/btrfs-corrupt-block.c), you can just check that out and compile it.